# In R, how can I perform a calculation which specifies (by ID) that IF the habitat is the same, ADD areas together

Tags: r

I have a dataset which similar to the below based on individual parcels of habitat present within each of my ID plots.

```
ID   Habitat    Area
1    Woodland   2
1    Woodland   5
1    Bog        9
2    Grassland  3
2    Bog        11
2    Grassland  7
2    Coastal    2
```

I want to know the cumulative area of each habitat per ID. Therefore I want to perform a calculation which says: By ID, IF the Habitat is the same, calculate the combined area of said habitat.

The output would hopefully look something like the below:

```
ID   Habitat    Area
1    Woodland   7
1    Bog        9
2    Grassland  10
2    Bog        11
2    Coastal    2
```

How could I go about writing this IF statement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `aggregate(Area ~ ., df, sum)` or `df %>% summarise(Area = sum(Area), .by = c(ID, Habitat))`